# Outlook doesn't pick up that email has been moved

Tags: email, outlook

I have an email account that I read with Thunderbird via IMAP on my PC, and I have rules to move emails into other folders.

I also have Outlook on my Android phone, and it constantly shows all emails in my Inbox, even ones that have been moved by rule to other folders. It is as if Outlook has cached the email and doesn't check to see if it's actually still there.

How can I force the Outlook app to refresh and detect this?

Answer (score 0):

First, verify via Outlook online if the emails have really moved to other folders. If not, make sure you create the rule online.

If yes, you must delete Outlook's data on your phone (Settings -> Apps & notifications -> Outlook -> Storage -> Clear storage), then re-add your account.

Answer (score 0):

I finally moved my rules to the server and this seems to address the problem, I suppose because the emails never hit the original folder in the first place.